# Creating a loading indicator delay with @ngrx/effects

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm experimenting with creating an effect that will delay a loading indicator so that it doesn't flash or flicker every time I'm retrieving data from the API. This is likely a case of not knowing what to search for, as I'm sure I can't be the only person who wants to give the API 300–500 ms to respond before tossing such an indicator onto the screen.

```
  @Effect() startDelayTimer: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(uiActions.START_LOADING_DELAY_TIMER)
    .switchMap(action => Observable
      .timer(300)
      .mapTo(new uiActions.LoadingDelayTimerCompleteAction));
```

Is there anything that will disrupt this effect from completing? I'm logging all of my action/state pairs to the console, and START_LOADING_DELAY_TIMER is being called, but the completion never is.

**Edit**

This question was asked prematurely, because the problem I was having ended up being unrelated. Here is the final implementation in case anyone else finds this question:

```
@Effect() startDelayTimer: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(uiActions.START_LOADING_DELAY_TIMER)
    .switchMap(action => Observable
      .timer(5000)
      .takeUntil(this.actions$.ofType(uiActions.CANCEL_LOADING_DELAY_TIMER))
      .mapTo(new uiActions.LoadingDelayTimerCompleteAction)
  )
```

- Start a timer to delay loading indicator flashing
- If a `CancelLoadingDelayTimerAction` is dispatched (likely from the completion of data retrieval from an API), stop the timer and do not show the loading indicator.
- If the timer completes before `CancelLoadingDelayTimerAction` is dispatched, then show the loading indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.timer(300)`, use `.delay(300)`. That should solve your problem.

Timer emits numbers on a given interval, which will probably cause some weird behavior with your effects. Delay simply throttles the stream for a given amount of time, which I think is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, my issues was being caused by a [completely unrelated problem](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/132)

Comment: Also, I'm using `Observable.timer()` to aid in cancellation. It's not apparent from the code above, so I will update to make this a more useful question for others.